# Error in writing a grayscale image

Tags: java, image-processing

In the following code am trying to read a grayscale image, store the pixel values in a 2D array and rewrite the image with a different name.
The code is

```
    package dct;

    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
    import java.awt.image.Raster;
    import java.io.File;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

    public class writeGrayScale
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            File file = new File("lightning.jpg");
            BufferedImage img = null;
            try
            {
                img = ImageIO.read(file);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            int width = img.getWidth();
            int height = img.getHeight();
            int[][] arr = new int[width][height];

            Raster raster = img.getData();

            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
                {
                    arr[i][j] = raster.getSample(i, j, 0);
                }
            }

            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(256, 256, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
            byte[] raster1 = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
            System.arraycopy(arr,0,raster1,0,raster1.length);
            //
            BufferedImage image1 = image;
            try
            {
                File ouptut = new File("grayscale.jpg");
                ImageIO.write(image1, "jpg", ouptut);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
        }// main
    }// class
```

For this code , the error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at dct.writeGrayScale.main(writeGrayScale.java:49)
Java Result: 1
```

How to remove this error to write the grayscale image?

Comment: You're trying to copy from a two-dimensional array (`int[][] arr`) into a one-dimensional (`byte[] raster1`), which is probably causing the problem.

Comment: Ok... I tried making byte[][]..its a syntax error of the method it seems...Any help in rewriting the statement " byte[] raster1 = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this: "ArrayStoreException -- if an element in the src array could not be stored into the dest array because of a type mismatch." http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm

Two thoughts:

1. You're copying an int-array into a byte-array.
2. That's not part of the exceptions, but are the dimensions right? arr is a two-dimensional array, raster1 is a one-dimensional array.

And you can't just change the byte-array in a two-dimensional one ignoring the output of the method you're calling.

Comment: What do you suggest to be changed now?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to rethink what you're trying to do. After copying values into raster1, you don't even use raster1 in your code anymore. So commenting the two lines out wouldn't even change your code's behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Change `int[][] arr` to `byte[] arr` like this.

```
    byte[] arr = new byte[width * height * 4];
    for (int i = 0, z = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++, z += 4) {
            int v = getSample(i, j, 0);
            for (int k = 3; k >= 0; --k) {
                arr[z + k] = (byte)(v & 0xff);
                v >>= 8;
            }
        }
    }
```